# Update jenkins selenium plugin to version 3.0.1

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins

I want to update jenkins selenium plugin (latest version: 2.53.1).
I can configure selenium hub and nodes outside of jenkins and run my automated tests with latest browser versions (firefox 51.0.1, chrome 55.0.2883.87) successfully but I just want to use jenkins as hub.

So that's why I'm trying to integrate the newest version of the **selenium-server-standalone (3.0.1)** into Jenkins but it's not working.

Getting this error messages:

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.jenkins-ci.tools:maven-hpi-plugin:jar:1.117 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to build parent project for org.jenkins-ci.plugins:selenium:hpi:2.53.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]Building Jenkins Selenium Plugin 2.53.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-hpi-plugin:1.117:validate (default-validate) @ selenium ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:display-info (display-info) @ selenium ---
[INFO] Maven Version: 3.3.9
[INFO] JDK Version: 1.8.0_121 normalized as: 1.8.0-121
[INFO] OS Info: Arch: amd64 Family: unix Name: linux Version: 4.4.0-62-generic
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (display-info) @ selenium ---
[INFO] Restricted to JDK 1.7 yet org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server-standalone:jar:3.0.1:compile contains org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.class targeted to JDK 1.8
[WARNING] Rule 2: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.EnforceBytecodeVersion failed with message:
Found Banned Dependency: org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server-standalone:jar:3.0.1
Use 'mvn dependency:tree' to locate the source of the banned dependencies.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.325 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-15T16:42:25+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 62M/1133M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (display-info) on project selenium: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

pom.xml of maven project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>fake</groupId>
    <artifactId>fake</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>${selenium.version}</version>

    <name>fake</name>

    <properties>
        <selenium.short.version>3.0</selenium.short.version>
        <selenium.version>${selenium.short.version}.1</selenium.version>
        <htmlunit.driver.version>2.20</htmlunit.driver.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <get
                                    src="http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/${selenium.short.version}/selenium-server-standalone-${selenium.version}.jar"
                                    dest="${project.build.directory}/selenium-server-standalone-${selenium.version}.jar"
                                    verbose="on" usetimestamp="true" />
                                <get
                                    src="https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver/releases/download/${htmlunit.driver.version}/htmlunit-driver-standalone-${htmlunit.driver.version}.jar"
                                    dest="${project.build.directory}/htmlunit-driver-standalone-${htmlunit.driver.version}.jar"
                                    verbose="on" usetimestamp="true" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>selenium-server-standalone</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <file>${project.build.directory}/selenium-server-standalone-${selenium.version}.jar</file>
                            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                            <artifactId>selenium-server-standalone</artifactId>
                            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <localRepositoryPath>local_m2</localRepositoryPath>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>htmlunit-driver-standalone</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <file>${project.build.directory}/htmlunit-driver-standalone-${htmlunit.driver.version}.jar</file>
                            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                            <artifactId>htmlunit-driver-standalone</artifactId>
                            <version>${htmlunit.driver.version}</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>

                            <localRepositoryPath>local_m2</localRepositoryPath>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Code : https://github.com/jenkinsci/selenium-plugin

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.2; Eclipse Neon Java IDE ,openjdk version "1.8.0_121"

I've already tried it out with openjdk 1.7 as well but it's still not working.

I'm quite a newbie at this so I appreciate any help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is simple : The Jenkins plugin's parent pom enforces by default to JDK7. Selenium libraries have moved on to using JDK8. That explains the error message arising from the enforcer plugin.

Here's how the enforcer plugin has been configured in the [parent pom](http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/plugin/2.9/plugin-2.9.pom)

`<java.level>7</java.level>`

```
<enforceBytecodeVersion>
  <maxJdkVersion>1.${java.level}</maxJdkVersion>
  <ignoredScopes>
    <ignoredScope>test</ignoredScope>
  </ignoredScopes>
  <excludes>
    <!-- Makes no sense to check core itself: -->
    <exclude>org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-core</exclude>
    <exclude>org.jenkins-ci.main:cli</exclude>
    <exclude>org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-test-harness</exclude>
    <!--  findbugs dep managed to provided and optional so is not shipped and missing annotations ok -->
    <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:annotations</exclude>
  </excludes>
</enforceBytecodeVersion>
```

To fix this, you have two options [ I have never tried this, but its something that you can try and see if it helps ] (Both these options I am suggesting based on the recommendations from your parent pom itself )

- Try passing the JVM argument `-Djava.level=8` when you build the code.
- Add an entry such as below to your pom file (This will cause enforcer plugin to perhaps ignore only the selenium libraries)

  maven-enforcer-plugin
      
          
              display-info
              
                  
                      
                          
                            org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:*:jar:compile
                            org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:*:jar:compile

Hope that helps!

**update**
I spent more time looking at this and realised that moving over to selenium 3.0.1 for this plug-in was not very straight forward. I have tried doing the changes and raised a [pull request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/selenium-plugin/pull/101) for the same. You can take a look at the PR and see if that helps.

PS : I still have 3 tests failing in the PR. I haven't figured out how to get them to pass. But the PR should help you get started. You can directly checkout my branch and try building from there.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and help. I understand the cause and I've tried your options out. Unfortunately none of those options are working.    error messages: -first option
...
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (display-info) on project selenium: Execution display-info of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce failed: Unknown JDK version given. Should be something like "1.7" -> [Help 1]
...  Do you have other ideas? I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: @Jaw.M.- I have updated my answer. Please take a look and accept it if it helped.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help. Is it required to change the htmlunit-driver-standalone to version 3.0.1? The latest offical version is 2.20. I got some issues when I'm trying it out with the 3.0.1 version and your changes of your pr : ... [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project selenium: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.jenkins-ci.plugins:selenium:hpi:2.53.2-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.seleniumhq.selenium:htmlunit-driver-standalone:jar:3.0.1 in file:///home/.../git/selenium-plugin/dist-server-standalone/local_m2 was cached in the local repository

Comment: PS: I've already tried it out with version 2.20 and your changes but unfortunately it's not working either .

Comment: The html unit standalone dependency is a local dependency and doesn't exist in maven. If u pay close attention to my changeset you will notice that we r actually checking in the Uber jar as well. My changes should compile as is without any problems. Like I said there r test failures but I haven't spent time figuring out why they fail.

Comment: Thanks for your help.